# java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database in Ktor application:

```
fun initDB() {
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC"
    val driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    Database.connect(url, driver)
}
```

...

```
fun getUsers(): String {
    var json = ""
    transaction {
        val dbResult = Users.selectAll().orderBy(Users.lastName, true).limit(10)
        ...
        json = Gson().toJson(users);
    }
    return json
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password'

Why does it happen? And how to fix it?

**UPD**

Eventually I've found a way to fix it: I've created new user in MySQL by command

```
CREATE USER 'nativeuser'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

then granted him all privileges and reconnected with new credentials. But the first question is still actual, because I don't have any settings like

```
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password
```

in my *my.ini* file.

Comment: I don't see anything related to ktor. Are you using exposed? Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? The version you're using is likely too old to support caching_sha2_password (which I believe is the default in recent MySQL versions)

Comment: @AndreasVolkmann, yes, I'm using Exposed.

Comment: Probably the driver is too old. The newer versions use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` as the driver name.